# Validate Date function always returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a code to validate the dates and this is causing a trouble, the fields have the same class which is called as .date

So i have this Code

```
function validateDates() {
let ok = true;
const dateInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
for (let i = 0; i < dateInputs.length; i++) {
    const idate = dateInputs[i].value.trim();
    if (idate && !isValidDate(idate)) {
        console.log(idate);
        console.log(!isValidDate(idate));
        console.log(idate && !isValidDate(idate))
        ok = false;
        console.log('log' + ok);
    }
}
return ok;
}
```

here is the function i am usding for validation

```
function isValidDate(dateString) {
    const dateParts = dateString.split("/");
    if (dateParts.length !== 3) {
        console.log('A');
        return false;
    }
    let day, month, year;
    if (dateParts[0].length === 2 && dateParts[1].length === 2) {
        day = parseInt(dateParts[0]);
        month = parseInt(dateParts[1]);
        year = parseInt(dateParts[2]);
        console.log('x');
    } else if (dateParts[1].length === 2 && dateParts[0].length === 2) {
        day = parseInt(dateParts[1]);
        month = parseInt(dateParts[0]);
        year = parseInt(dateParts[2]);
        console.log('y');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    if (isNaN(day) || isNaN(month) || isNaN(year)) {
        console.log('b');
        return false;
    }
    const maxDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    if (year % 4 === 0 && (year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 === 0)) {
        maxDays[1] = 29; // Leap year
    }
    if (day < 1 || day > maxDays[month - 1]) {
        return false;
        console.log('c');
    }
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        return false;
        console.log('d');
    }
    return true;
}
```

so once the code is returning false, it never comes out of that, what is wrong i am doing in the above function

the code i tried i already posted above

i am trying to validate `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` format dates

Comment: You set `ok = false` if one of the dates is invalid, and never set `ok` back to `true`. Is that what you intended with the loop - return `false` if any single date field is invalid? Did you write this code? The logging there should clearly tell you which date string your code thinks is invalid. `isValidDate('01/01/1990')` with your code returns true.

Comment: so how can i fix it

Comment: ` so how can i fix it` - depends on your intended logic `once the code is returning false, it never comes out of that` what is `it` and what is `that` that `it` "doesn't come out of"?

Comment: you do realise `console.log('c');` and `console.log('d');` can never be executed? - and `else if (dateParts[1].length === 2 && dateParts[0].length === 2)` can never be tested `if (dateParts[0].length === 2 && dateParts[1].length === 2)` since they are testing the same condition, so when the `if` is true, `else if` never gets run, and when `if` is false, so is `else if` - so ... completely irrelevant code

Comment: if it is completely irrelevant code, then please guide me to rewrite a function which will verify its dates and when its true and i can move fwd with new things and let this logic be clear out, i am herre for help, not about my code review